# Loading VCL-Styles from Reources

Tags: c++, resources, c++builder, vcl-styles

Does anyone have experience with using resource for styles. I'm working on a program for which we created a custom Style. We saved it as .style and as .vsf. Because we don't want the user to see/change the style of the programm we want to include it in our resource file (.res) This is done as explained in next Link: [Customizing and Creating VCL Styles](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/customizing-and-creating-vcl-styles) Afterwards the created file (Tested with .style and .vsf) is placed in the Resourcefile as RC Data.
Thats the preparation, now what didn't work. (tWinMain)

```
TStyleManager::SetStyle(TStyleManager::LoadFromResource((unsigned int)HInstance, "StyleName", RT_RCDATA));
```

This also doesn't work:

```
TStyleManager::LoadFromResource((unsigned int)HInstance, "StyleName", RT_RCDATA);
TStyleManager::SetStyle("StyleName");
```

also not working

```
TStyleManager_TStyleServicesHandle MyStyle;
MyStyle = TStyleManager::LoadFromResource((unsigned int)HInstance, "StyleName", RT_RCDATA);
TStyleManager::SetStyle(MyStyle);
```

All three methodes resulting in the error message: Invalid Style-handle

Loading the same style from a file works:

```
TStyleManager::LoadFromFile(stylePath + "StyleName.vsf");
TStyleManager::SetStyle("StyleName");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Delphi (DX10.3) and the following worked for me

Basically the same call of "TStyleManager::LoadFromResource", but without the specification of the optional parameter "RT_RCDATA".

```
MyStyle = TStyleManager::LoadFromResource((unsigned int)HInstance, "StyleName");
TStyleManager::SetStyle(MyStyle);
```

But then the resource type "VCLSTYLE" is necessary to load the style correctly. When adding the resource in the IDE, with [Project] > [Resources and Pics...] you can only specify RCDATA in the dialog, which is bad. But you can enter the resource type directly manual with the keyboard as "VCLSTYLE". The IDE remembers this setting and now the resource is available as the correct type. As said before, it works with Delphi 10.3, with the Builder it depends on one try.

[Resource-type manual input in IDE dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM1vo.png)

Best regards, Matthias

Comment: You solved my problem at delphi, many thanks!